# Exponential weighting for infinite and finite series

Tags: programming

in dealing with financial time series, should I consider a dataset to be finite in calculating exponential moving averages?

From the `Pandas` documentation [1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#stats-moments-exponentially-weighted), finite series should be using the `adjust=False` parameter. Is this correct, as the use of `adjust=True` yields different result?

Answer (score 1):

Does it really matter? It is an initialization issue, and once you have enough data the two methods will converge. `adjust=False` calculation is simpler, but `adjust=True` is theoretically better suited to a finite series (yes, I think it is the opposite of what you said). Probably most people still use the simpler, older method, but since the computer does all the work you don't really care about complexity. I would use `True` unless you want to match the results from an existing system that uses the simple method (and notice that Pandas makes True the default).

Finite vs infinite is a red herring, all observed series are finite. It is the simple formula from the 1950s when they did calculations by hand, or the other slightly more sophisticated slightly newer formula. Some people want to stick with the old formula, so Pandas provides `adjust=False` for these traditionalists.